# Expecting an error in TCL for the code for non initialization of variable

Tags: tcl

I have the below small code I am expecting the TCL interpreter to throw error for the variable not initialized but it not throwing an error

```
set v1 "test" 
if { ($v1 != "test") && ($v2 == "3") } { 
  puts "fun" 
} 
#v2 is not initialized
```

No error is being thrown by interpreter for v2 , as it not initialized

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, the sublanguage of `expr` in TCL, (which is also used in `if`, `while`, `for`) works in another way than TCL itself. In this sublanguage, `$` doesn't mean variable substitution, but a variable reference. Variables are accessed when their containing subexpressions are evaluated. And logical operations are short-circuiting, evaluating operands from left to right *until the result is known*, as in C language.

That's why `$v2 == 3` is not evaluated in your example, and nonexistent `$v2` is not an error. This behavior is commonly used with code like this:

```
if {[info exists myvar] && $myvar} { .... }
```

Comment: @DonalFellows with respect to `&&` and `||` (where C promises short-circuiting behaviour), ANSI C is strict left-to-right. For other operations, yes: `expr` is left-to-right for `{[proc1]+[proc2]}`, and C is not.